# left join with where in right table

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join, where-clause

I have this Join: Table mmp_user **151 users** 
Table MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG **URL's access**

```
    select user.name as 'Usuário',count(log.referer) as 'Número de Acessos'
from mmp_user user
left JOIN MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG log on (user.id=log.user_id)
where log.event_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-08'
group by user.id
order by count(log.referer) desc
```

expected outcome: **151 lines**
obtained results: **11 lines**

Help me please

Comment: move the where condition to joining condition `on (user.id=log.user_id) and log.event_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-08'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
SELECT u.name as 'Usuário',count(log.referer) as 'Número de Acessos'
FROM mmp_user u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, referer
    FROM MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG
    WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-08'
) log ON u.id=log.user_id
group by u.id
order by count(log.referer) desc
```

ps. next time don't use 'user', it's not clear